# JSF, refresh periodically a component with ajax?

Tags: ajax, jsf, notifications, refresh

I'm working on an application JSF and i want to refresh periodically a component with ajax Like facebook notification zone behaviour.
How can i do that?

Comment: In the future questions it would be helpful if you explicitly mention what component libraries you all use, like PrimeFaces. If you don't mention anything, standard JSF would always be assumed.

Answer (score 34):

Poll is what you need to use

> Poll component make ajax calls in a specified interval.

For example Primefaces Poll

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:outputText id="txt_count" value="#{counterBean.count}" />
    <p:poll interval="3" listener="#{counterBean.increment}" update="txt_count" />
</h:form>
```

Link to showcase [Primefaces Ajax Poll](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml)

Pure JSF approach would be to use js timer that will invoke periodical `document.getElementById('someFormId:idOfButton').click();`

or jquery `$("#someFormId\\:idOfButton").click();`

while the button will look like this

```
<h:commandButton id="idOfButton">
    <f:ajax render="txt_count"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

something like this

```
setInterval(function(){$("idOfButton").click()},3000);
```

More about timer [JavaScript Timing Events](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Comment: Based on OP's question history, he's using PrimeFaces, so that's a perfect suit.

Answer (score 5):

In RichFaces there is a poll component as well. Here is a nice example [they](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_poll.html) provide

```
<a4j:region>
      <h:form>
            <a4j:poll id="poll" interval="1000" enabled="#{userBean.pollEnabled}" reRender="poll,grid"/>
      </h:form>
</a4j:region>

<h:form>
      <h:panelGrid columns="2" width="80%" id="grid">
           <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                <h:outputText value="Polling Inactive" rendered="#{not userBean.pollEnabled}" />
                <h:outputText value="Polling Active" rendered="#{userBean.pollEnabled}" />
                <a4j:commandButton style="width:120px" id="control" value="#{userBean.pollEnabled?'Stop':'Start'} Polling" reRender="poll, grid">  
                     <a4j:actionparam name="polling" value="#{!userBean.pollEnabled}" assignTo="#{userBean.pollEnabled}"/>
                </a4j:commandButton>
          </h:panelGrid>
          <h:outputText id="serverDate" style="font-size:16px" value="Server Date: #{userBean.date}"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```