# auto refresh a div using JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

How to automatically refresh a div every 5 seconds using JSF. I have a div with id = statusBlock, I want the status and comments inside it to get updated automatically every 5 seconds so that user automatically gets all the status updates without refreshing the whole page. I have searched the stackoverflow site but couldn't find anything that would let me do it using JSF.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11228281/617373

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF, refresh periodically a component with ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228198/jsf-refresh-periodically-a-component-with-ajax)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be achieved using [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) JavaScript function that makes a call to the server once a while.

A simple but not so fancy example would be executing a hidden `UICommand` in order that user can't update the data by him/herself:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function() { 
        document.getElementById('myForm:btnLoadData').submit();
        }, 5*1000);
</script>

<h:panelGroup id="divData" layout="block">
    <!-- content... -->
</h:panelGroup>
<h:form id="myForm">
    <h:commandButton id="btnLoadData" value="Hidden" action="#{bean.loadData}"
        style="display:none">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":divData" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Comment: What if I don't want to use a hidden UICommand, what changes I need to do if I only want to refresh `<h:panelGroup id='divData'>`

Comment: You should make an ajax request to the server manually like explained [here](http://www.developer.com/java/web/article.php/10935_3870686_2/Inside-JSF-20s-Ajax-and-HTTP-GET-Support.htm). Note that the `UICommand` heavily helps you doing this stuff. Also, you can always recur to third party libraries that handle this work like PrimeFaces (as stated in @RodrigoSasaki's answer).

Comment: can I ommit the action attribute. Will it cause any problem if I remove the `action="#{bean.loadData}"`.Is it mandatoyr?

Comment: @AmlanKarmakar it won't cause any danger, it will just send a POST request and won't execute any action at all.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: could u please explain the @ form in ajax execute="@form". I am newbie in jsf, trying to implement your solution

Comment: @ajitksharma `execute="@form"` means that the whole data in `<h:form>` will be send to the server. If you need to send specific data, you can use `execute=":icomponent1Id :component2Id ..."` and on.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: setinterval method is not working. It is refreshing. what can be the problem

Comment: @ajitksharma you should post a question asking about your specific case.

Comment: could u please reply to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26151422/auto-refresh-in-jsf-using-ajax

Answer (score 2):

Are you using any component lib such as Primefaces?

If you are you could use a polling component.

Here is a showcase link to exemplify: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/poll.jsf

Comment: In latests posts, OP asked if the answer can use plain JSF.