# Auto refresh in JSF using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, richfaces

I am using this code in my .xhtml page

In head tag, i am using for refresh purpose,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   alert("hi");
   setInterval(function() { 
    document.getElementById('myForm:btnLoadData').submit();
    alert("Hello");
    }, 3000);
</script>
```

and inside **ui:define** tag i am writing this code.

```
<h:panelGroup id="divData" layout="block">

//my jsf code..................

</h:panelGroup>

<h:form id="myForm">
<h:commandButton id="btnLoadData" value="Hidden" style="display:none">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":divData" />
</h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

After all this I am not getting any error, but the hidden button is not working as desired in script. Even I cant see the alert("Hello").

> Update: I can see the first alert("hi") but not alert("Hello")

I am newbie in jsf. I have to implement polling type thing or auto refresh.
I also tried [this example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml). But its not working.

**Problem 2**
I dont know that much jsf. At some places I am using normal HTML tags. I dont know why URL is not showing the page name. Its always like host/myProjectName. I am expecting host/projectName/Login.xhtml or host/projectName/SomeOtherPage.xhtml
Even browser back button or reload for that particular page not works. It reloads from first page of my project i-e Login page. Are both problems interrelated. How can I handle this.

Somebody please help me with the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the generated HTML includes both the JavaScript and the HTML code from your JSF code? Also, can you check the generated id for your `brnLoadData` JSF component in the rendered HTML?

Comment: I cheked generated id for brnLoadData JSF component in the rendered HTML and that is correct. Also generated HTML has both the script and HTML code. I can see the script tag and generated html on inspect element of browser

Comment: Since you state that there's no sign of execution of `alert("Hello");`, seems that the previous JavAScript command couldn't be executed. Use your Browser console (Chrome console, Firebug or another) and check if `document.getElementById('myForm:btnLoadData')` works for your case. If it doesn't, check the exact id for your component and fix the JavaScript code accordingly.

Comment: Problem1: search for primefaces pool, it is used for refresh purposes. Problem 2: search for faces-redirect, you will find out. If you need something else, let me know :)

Comment: I just see that you already tried to implement the component pool with no success. Just post a question to solve it, dont try to implement it with JavaScript, the components are there so we can use !